# Getting a "method not found [404]" error from dev console while working with meteor collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to insert a document into my meteor collection with an autoform made from my mongo schema, yet when I press the submit button it is giving me a "method not found [404]" error in the dev console.  I believe it is coming from this code:

```
GameList.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc){
    return !!userId;
  }
});
```

which allows people to add documents to the database if they are logged in as a user. Without this code I will receive a "not authorized [403]" error, because I took out the insecure package from my meteor app.  Any idea on what is causing this method not found error?

Autoform code:

```
{{> quickForm collection="GameList" id="insertGameForm" type="insert" class="newGameForm"}}
```

Schema for autoform:

```
GameListSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title"
  },
  platform: {
    type: String,
    label: "Platform"
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    label: "Category"
  },
  gameRank: {
    type: String,
    label: "GameRank"
  },
  auth: {
    type: String,
    label: "Author",
    autoValue: function(){
      return this.userId
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  }
});

GameList.attachSchema(GameListSchema);
```

Comment: Can you add in your autoform code?

Comment: @StephenWoods just did there ya go

Comment: Are the allow/deny rules running on server code or client code?

Comment: @stephenwoods they are running on client code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is happening because your [allow/deny rules](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) are supposed to run on the server according to the Meteor documentation.  Try putting them on server-side code and running this again.